# Why use the kanji 伸 for "no" instead of the hiragana の, and the kanji 手 for "te" instead of the hiragana て?

Tags: usage, kanji, orthography, kana, written-language

In an [anime opening song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIkeB9EE0rs), at 0:08, I read the following sentence:

> *omokage no naka te wo nobasu no*
>   おもかげのなか　手を伸ばすの

Please, can you tell me:

- for "no", why is the kanji 伸 used instead of the hiragana の?
- for "te", why is the kanji 手 used instead of the hiragana て?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is unusual? For example why do you think it's okay to have 手 instead of て?

Comment: Yes you're right. There is also the case you say! And I am interested also in that one! I edit the post!

Comment: I feel like I'm not grasping something here. Are you familiar with normal Japanese orthography? Is this show targeted at small children?

Comment: @virmaior I am a very beginner about Japanese! However, I am very courious, and my questions could be sometimes very trivial... sorry. And, no, I'm not familiar with japanese orthography.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the word is 伸ばす. The 伸 kanji for this word has a reading of の.

As you might already know, Japanese has three distinct writing systems (not counting romanizations): ひらがな, カタカナ, and 漢字｛かんじ｝. It is preferable when possible and when it is normal to use 漢字 in your writing because, while ひらがな and カタカナ are syllabic characters, 漢字 convey ideas and don't have a fixed syllabic value in Japanese.

What this means is that 漢字 have multiple ways of being read, and their readings are mainly grouped into two categories, which are 訓読｛くんよ｝み and 音読｛おんよ｝み. There is an additional category which is 熟字訓｛じゅくじくん｝ when a character or set of characters have a reading outside of these two standard categories. Use of 漢字 in writing helps distinguish a word for its meaning rather than its sound.

Say, for example, that you see いって written down, without much context. How would you be able to tell if the word was meant to be いって (て-form of 行｛い｝く, to go), or いって (て-form of 言｛い｝う, to say)? They are pronounced the same way. 漢字 help discern what the true meaning of the word is, as it is written. Therefore, you should try to use 漢字 when you learn it, so that your written Japanese is more clearly understood.

I should add a note: Some words are more commonly written in かな than in 漢字. As you study, you'll learn which these are, and why this is the case. You may, for example, use the 漢字　for 居{い}る but more commonly you'll see it written as いる instead. That's another thing to keep in mind, and something you'll pick up along the way.

Comment: 居て is read _ite_, not _itte_.  :)

Comment: Can you add also the case of 手? At its right there's the particle を, so why not to use the hiragana て?.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi yes, you're right. I've changed my answer

Comment: @JB-Franco The answer to that is in the last sentence: "You should try to use 漢字 when you learn it, so that your written Japanese is more clearly understood." In other words, using 漢字 in your writing is a matter of clarity and of speaking/writing in an educated manner. You'd use 手 instead of て or テ because you would want to be clear you're speaking about a "hand", which is what the 手 means. The other かな characters don't convey a meaning to the sound て

Comment: @JB-Franco Also (you may not believe me right now, but) reading text with kanji is a lot easier than reading a long string of hiragana. They really help to separate out the word boundaries and grammar in a much clearer way then if it were all hiragana.

Comment: @JB-Franco, to follow up on user3856370's comment, imagine if you had to read English withnocapitalizationandnospaces.forwrittenjapanese,kanjicontrastwithkanainawaysimilartotheuseofspacesandcapitalizationineuropeanlanguages.thoseextrapartsofourwritingsystemcanreallyhelptomakethingsmorelegible.  :)

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi great example!

Comment: @psosuna therefore, using テ, it can be good because you can obtain separation, but, you can convey to its meaning once you have read the entire sentence, instead, using 手 you can arrive to its meaning immediately.

Comment: @JB-Franco Well, don't think too hard on it. Just remember that if you know the Kanji and it is acceptable to use, you should use it.